# How to use put() in a subclass of Java's TreeMap

Tags: java, subclass

I want to create a subclass of class of java.util.TreeMap, to allow me to add an increment method:

```
public class CustomTreeMap<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
  public void increment(Integer key) {
    Integer intValue;

    if (this.containsKey(key)) {
      Object value = this.get(key);
      if (!(value instanceof Integer)) {
        // Fail gracefully
        return;

      } else {
        intValue = (Integer) value;
        intValue++;
      }
    } else {
      intValue = 1;
    }

    this.put(key, intValue); // put(Integer, Integer) cannot be applied in TreeMap
  }
}
```

Android Studio 1.0.2 first proposes `put(K Key, V Value)` for autocompletion, and later warns that:

```
put(K, V) cannot be applied in TreeMap to (java.lang.integer, java.lang.integer)
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831718/what-java-collection-considers-permutations-to-be-equal) for the solution I adopted.

Comment: You define both K and V as generic, why are you defining them when both are actually `Integer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your custom treemap to handle `Integers` exclusively, you should make it extend `TreeMap<K, Integer>`, not the generic type `V`:

```java
public class CustomTreeMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
  ...
}
```

This way you don't need the `instanceof` check later.

If your key also needs to be an `Integer`, declare no generic types instead:

```java
public class CustomTreeMap extends TreeMap<Integer, Integer> {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it should be Integer then use Integer:

```
public class CustomTreeMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
  public void increment(K key) {
    Integer intValue;

    if (this.containsKey(key)) {
      Object value = this.get(key);
      if (!(value instanceof Integer)) {
        // Fail gracefully
        return;

      } else {
        intValue = (Integer) value;
        intValue++;
      }
    } else {
      intValue = 1;
    }

    this.put(key, intValue); // put(Integer, Integer) cannot be applied in TreeMap
  }
}
```