# How do I unit test for a Collection parameter with an Collection return?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, arraylist, collections

I have a method that takes in a Collection of type T as a parameter and returns a Collection of type Integer. In this specific instance, I'm trying to return an ArrayList (am I wrong to do that? I figured since an ArrayList inherits from a Collection, that should be okay).

```
@Test public void test() {
  Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(2);
  list.add(8);
  list.add(7);
  list.add(3);
  list.add(4);
  Comparison comp = new Comparison();
  int low = 1;
  int high = 5;
  ArrayList<Integer> actual = SampleClass.<Integer>range(list, low, high, comp);
  ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  expected.add(2);
  expected.add(3);
  expected.add(4);
  Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

As requested, here is the discussed method:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> range(Collection<T> coll, T low, T high,
                                     Comparator<T> comp) {
  if (coll == null || comp == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Collection or Comparator.");
  }
  if (coll.size() == 0) {
     throw new NoSuchElementException("Collection is empty.");
  }
  ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (T t : coll) {
     if (comp.compare(t, low) >= 0 && comp.compare(t, high) <= 0) {
        al.add(t);
     }
  }
  return al;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you paste the code for SampleClass.range.

Comment: It gives me an incompatible types error: incompatible types: Collection<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<>(SampleClass.<Integer>range(list, low, high, comp));`?

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks! Could you explain the syntax behind that?

Comment: @Alvarno Collection<Integer> cannot be assigned to ArrayList<Integer>. You would need to add a cast or do as Andy suggested. That said could you show the method that takes Collection<T> and returns Collection<Integer>?

Comment: @Alvarno ArrayList<E> has a constructor ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection) that Andy is using. You could also add a cast actual = (ArrayList<Integer>)SampleClass.... although with this you must be sure your method actually returns an ArrayList. I prefer Andy's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment from Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298377/how-do-i-unit-test-for-a-collection-parameter-with-an-collection-return#comment58307525_35298377) suggests copying the returned collection into an `ArrayList`, which can then be compared to another `ArrayList` using `equals()`. This makes the code compile and presumably lets the test pass.

The fact that the potential solutions include casting the result or copying it into a container of a different type raise some questions about what's actually going on here.

Copying the result `Collection` into a `List` makes some possibly unwarranted assumptions about the `range()` method. It's declared to return a `Collection`. If your test is modified to copy the result to a `List` and compares it to an expected result, also a `List`, the test constrains the `range()` implementation to produce its results in a particular order. If order is significant, perhaps `range()` should be modified to consume and return `List` instead of `Collection`.

But what if order doesn't matter? If the returned collection contained `[4, 3, 2]` instead of `[2, 3, 4]`, would that be acceptable? If so, then you'll need to compare the actual and expected results in an order-independent fashion. For techniques to do that, see this question:

[Is there a way to check if two Collections contain the same elements, independent of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565214/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-two-collections-contain-the-same-elements-independen)